# PHP - cronjob failing to execute on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I have a PHP file that I want to run as a cron job.

On the server the file is located at `/var/www/html/directory/file.php` and has no errors as it can be run in the browser by going to `www.exampledomain.com/directory/file.php`.

In the file `/etc/crontab` I have the following line:

`* * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/directory/file.php >/dev/null 2>&1`

On my server typing `sudo service cron status` I see:

```
● cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-07-29 10:23:11 UTC; 4 months 23 days ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 769 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 1140)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─769 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Dec 21 17:46:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20648]: (ubuntu) CMD (root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/directory/file.php >/dev/null
Dec 21 17:46:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20649]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/directory/file.php >/dev/null 2
Dec 21 17:46:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20647]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Dec 21 17:46:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20646]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Dec 21 17:47:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20661]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ubuntu by (uid=0)
Dec 21 17:47:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20660]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Dec 21 17:47:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20662]: (ubuntu) CMD (root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/directory/file.php >/dev/null
Dec 21 17:47:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20663]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/directory/file.php >/dev/null 2
Dec 21 17:47:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20661]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ubuntu
Dec 21 17:47:01 ip-172-31-34-251 CRON[20660]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

The cron job is supposed to update another file but that is not happening. What is going wrong or what can I do to troubleshoot this further. Previously I would have used cron as a service in a hosted domain but have only recently started using ubuntu so am unsure of linux commands.

Comment: `* * * * *` This expression means every minute. Are you sure that's how you want to run it?

Comment: @nice_dev I just had it set this way for troubleshooting it won't be running as often when I actually get it working

Comment: Ok. Can you manually hit on the command line like `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/directory/file.php` and check if another file is getting updated? It could be a permission issue for the other file.

Comment: Is tihs a PHP issue at all? Does anything else work? Make sure you follow the spirit of a [mcve] and remove irrelevant parts. Also, you actively suppressed all output, so you shouldn't be surprised to not get any diagnostic hint.

Comment: @nice_dev yes it works fine from the command line, its an issue with the cron setup. I had added `>/dev/null 2>&1` after reading another post saying it was trying to print some thing and email it to me but was getting an error with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use /etc/crontab to run your cron jobs. Instead use the user account that you wish to run the job under. The environment for system crons will almost never match what you need to run the job you want to do. So in this case, su to the root user and then `crontab -e` or `sudo crontab -e`. Then make your entry as such...

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/directory/file.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: thanks I had tried adding the cronjob from here, but had left in the 'root' part of the command, removing this worked.